# ServiceM8 custom fields

Tags: sql, database, integration, servicem8

The ServiceM8 API documentation on what can be referenced has no mention of custom fields. If a client has custom fields setup in ServiceM8 at a job and client level are you able to reference / pull this information from ServiceM8 through the API? We are looking at querying the ServiceM8 API to an SQL database and want to confirm if this information is available.

Answer (score 2):

Any custom fields you have on a particular account are visible on the API. They appear just like the regular job/company fields (status, description, job_address etc) but they will have a `customfield_` prefix.

So if you have a customfield on the Job object called "Registration Number" for instance, then when you query the Job endpoint it will show up like this:

```
[{
   "uuid":"8a3a10ee-3baa-4b5c-81f8-7684148da60b",
   "active":1,
   "date":"2014-11-24 00:00:00",
   "job_address":"123 Job Address St",
   "status":"Work Order",
   "customfield_registration_number":"ABC123",

   ... etc
 }]
```

Comment: To clarify, the field that will display on the `job` endpoint is the `field_name` field, not the `display_name` field.  I.e.  You could have a `display_name` of "Registration Number", and a `field_name` of "registration_number", and the `job` endpoint object would then be `customfield_registration_number`